# Wordpress: how can I check if a specific value exists in a custom field without specifying a post ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to check, if a given number has been attributed to a custom field. 
How can I do that, without specifying the post ID?

details:

I created a custom post type in which I store a client number and wether or not the client has booked a service. 
The service is provided by handing the client a little code snippet (iframe, source is the url to said file in their website) so they can display some information.

I know want to do the following: I attach the clientnumber to the given url, like so: www.example-url.org?nr=123

If there is no number after the url, some fail message is displaied (I already managed to do that).

Now I want to check if the client number exists at all in my database. And only then should the booked information be displaied.

I checked the get_post_meta, but I need the post ID. Can I check  wether the number exists without knowing the post ID?

Comment: Please share code you have worked with. Help will follow

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet,

```
global $wpdb;

$metas = $wpdb->get_results( 
 $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = %s", 'add_your_key_here')
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $metas );
echo '</pre>';
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [How we get_post_meta without post id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94990/how-we-get-post-meta-without-post-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using custom query in wordpress. For that I create one function which will help you to check if this customer number is exist or not. Please have a look at below method.

```
$clinetnumber=get_meta_value_using_key($meta_key); // call the method 

// check if custom number is exist or not
if(!empty($clinetnumber) && $clinetnumber!=0) 
{
   echo "Customer number is already registered";
}
else 
{
   echo "Customer number is not registered";
}

function get_meta_value_using_key($meta_key)
{
   global $wpdb; 
   $query="SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s "; // meta query by key
   $result=$wpdb->prepare($query , $meta_key);
   $value = $wpdb->get_var($result); // get result of quesry

   return $value; // return value
```

}